# Why does my data not appear on the table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am given some school task, I am using React js and tailwindcss tools, I want to make a table that shows data.

I am using some sources I found on youtube, but not all the data was inserted into the table.

App.js code:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import "./App.css"; 
import data from  "./dataset.json";

const App = () => {
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState(data);

    return ( 
    <div className="app-container">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>NAMA</th>
                    <th>UMUR</th>
                    <th>TINGGI</th>
                    <th>BERAT BADAN</th>
                    <th>JENIS KELAMIN</th>
                    <th>TEKANAN SISTOLE</th>
                    <th>TEKANAN DIASTOLE</th>
                    <th>TINGKAT KOLESTEROL</th>
                    <th>TINGKAT GLUKOSA</th>
                    <th>PEROKOK AKTIF/TIDAK</th>
                    <th>ALKOHOLIK/TIDAK</th>
                    <th>AKTIVITAS FISIK</th>
                    <th>RIWAYAT PENYAKIT CARDIOVASCULAR</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {contacts.map((contacts)=> (
                <tr>
                  <td>{contacts.name}</td>
                  <td>{contacts.age}</td>
                  <td>{contacts.height}</td>
                  <td>{contacts.weight}</td>
                  <td>{contacts.gender}</td>
                  <td>{contacts.ap_hi}</td>
                  <td>{contacts.ap_lo}</td>
                  <td>{contacts.cholestrol}</td>
                  <td>{contacts.gluc}</td>
                  <td>{contacts.smoke}</td>
                  <td>{contacts.alco}</td>
                  <td>{contacts.active}</td>
                  <td>{contacts.cardio}</td>
                </tr>

              )
              
              
              )}
                
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

This App.css :

```css
.app-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 2rem;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 250%;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

th {
  background-color: rgb(117, 201, 250);
}

td {
  background-color: rgb(205, 235, 253);
}

form {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

form td:last-child {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

form * {
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

and this my dataset.json :

```json
[
    {
        "_id": "633664fd355fcafc3b1282cc",
        "name": "yazid",
        "age": 18,
        "height": 165,
        "weight": 55,
        "gender": true,
        "ap_hi": 130,
        "ap_lo": 85,
        "cholestrol": 1,
        "gluc": 1,
        "smoke": true,
        "alco": false,
        "active": true,
        "cardio": false,
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "63369d1d355fcafc3b1282da",
        "name": "ryan",
        "age": 18,
        "height": 165,
        "weight": 55,
        "gender": true,
        "ap_hi": 130,
        "ap_lo": 85,
        "cholestrol": 1,
        "gluc": 1,
        "smoke": true,
        "alco": false,
        "active": true,
        "cardio": false,
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

and here are few images of the UI

[Table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNC3B.png)   [Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwS31.png)  [Table 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvxff.png)

I don't know why, but the data in "gender", "smoke", "alco", "active" and "cardio" won't show on the table but the data on"name" which is a string its showing up

so I made changes to the data as follows

```
"smoke": "true",
"alco": "false",
"active": "true",
"cardio": "false",
```

but it still won't show any change.

if I set "smoke" to true I want it to show as "true"

and I also want to make a change for gender if it is true it should show as "man" and if it is false it should show as "woman" which I was not able to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
          <td>{contacts.name}</td>
          <td>{contacts.age}</td>
          <td>{contacts.height}</td>
          <td>{contacts.weight}</td>
          <td>{contacts.gender ? "man" : "woman"}</td>
          <td>{contacts.ap_hi}</td>
          <td>{contacts.ap_lo}</td>
          <td>{contacts.cholestrol}</td>
          <td>{contacts.gluc}</td>
          <td>{contacts.smoke?.toString()}</td>
          <td>{contacts.alco?.toString()}</td>
          <td>{contacts.active?.toString()}</td>
          <td>{contacts.cardio?.toString()}</td>
```

Comment: oh gosh, i learn it and didn't even try it. Thankyou so much, it work now.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for `useState` because you can map data directly, and just convert boolean to sting with `.toString()` function, there is no need for passing boolean in dataset as string. You should add `key` to each child inside element. This way React can handle the minimal DOM changes. You can pass `index` to each child or use `contact._id` as a `key` in your case. Also since React 17 you do not need to import React in every component.

React:

```
import "./App.css";
import data from "./dataset.json";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="app-container">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>NAMA</th>
            <th>UMUR</th>
            <th>TINGGI</th>
            <th>BERAT BADAN</th>
            <th>JENIS KELAMIN</th>
            <th>TEKANAN SISTOLE</th>
            <th>TEKANAN DIASTOLE</th>
            <th>TINGKAT KOLESTEROL</th>
            <th>TINGKAT GLUKOSA</th>
            <th>PEROKOK AKTIF/TIDAK</th>
            <th>ALKOHOLIK/TIDAK</th>
            <th>AKTIVITAS FISIK</th>
            <th>RIWAYAT PENYAKIT CARDIOVASCULAR</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data.map((contact, index) => (
            <tr key={index}>
              <td>{contact.name}</td>
              <td>{contact.age}</td>
              <td>{contact.height}</td>
              <td>{contact.weight}</td>
              <td>{contact.gender ? "man" : "women"}</td>
              <td>{contact.ap_hi}</td>
              <td>{contact.ap_lo}</td>
              <td>{contact.cholestrol}</td>
              <td>{contact.gluc}</td>
              <td>{contact.smoke.toString()}</td>
              <td>{contact.alco.toString()}</td>
              <td>{contact.active.toString()}</td>
              <td>{contact.cardio.toString()}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

dataset.json

```
[
  {
    "_id": "633664fd355fcafc3b1282cc",
    "name": "yazid",
    "age": 18,
    "height": 165,
    "weight": 55,
    "gender": true,
    "ap_hi": 130,
    "ap_lo": 85,
    "cholestrol": 1,
    "gluc": 1,
    "smoke": true,
    "alco": false,
    "active": true,
    "cardio": false,
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "63369d1d355fcafc3b1282da",
    "name": "ryan",
    "age": 18,
    "height": 165,
    "weight": 55,
    "gender": true,
    "ap_hi": 130,
    "ap_lo": 85,
    "cholestrol": 1,
    "gluc": 1,
    "smoke": true,
    "alco": false,
    "active": true,
    "cardio": false,
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```